# jquery hover fadein only works for a short moment! why?

Tags: jquery, css

I wrote the below codes. such that when my mouse hover to `imgforplaces_thumbnail`. The div `checkbutton` will display and overlay on div `testtest`.
However, the div `checkbutton` would just appear for 1-2 sec, and disappear. If i remove the position:absolute; in css in div `testtest`, div `checkbutton` would appear below of it.

Can anyone tell me why it only works for 1-2 sec?

I have two divs, `.testtest` and `.checkbutton`, they are wrapped by .imgforplaces_thumbnail1.

these are the divs:

```
echo '<div class=imgforplaces_thumbnail1 id=imgforplaces_thumbnail>';
        echo '<div class=testtest>';
        echo "<a class='ajax' href='image_color_box.php?id=".$row['id']."' title='Homer Defined'>";
        echo "<img src='../imgforplaces_thumbnail/" . $row['location_name'] . ".png' />";
        echo '</a>';
        echo '</div>';
        echo '<div class=checkbutton><img src="../images/fbloginbutton.png" /></div>';
    echo '</div>';
```

the css are as follows:

```
#imgforplaces_thumbnail {
    border: 10px solid #EEEEEE;
        float: left;
        margin: 20px;
        outline: 1px solid #CFCFCF;
        width: 300px;
    height: 225px;
    }

.checkbutton {
height: 40px;
width: 209px;
z-index: 2000;
margin: 0 auto;
}

.testtest {
    position: absolute;
}
```

the jquery hover function:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".checkbutton").hide();
$(".imgforplaces_thumbnail1").hover(function(){
$(".checkbutton", this).fadeIn("slow");
},
function(){
    $(".checkbutton", this).fadeOut("slow");
 });

});
```

Comment: use miliseconds instead of "slow" :)

Comment: Please, surround your class and id names with quotes! It greatly improves readability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think i know where is the problem:

both "testtest" and "checkbutton" have to put position:absolute;

that solved my problem. thanks everyone for your valuable input!

Answer (score 0):

you can also try to set specific time span value for fade-in and fade-out instead of using hard coded slow and fast attributes
like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".checkbutton").hide();
$(".imgforplaces_thumbnail1").hover(function(){
$(".checkbutton", this).fadeIn(200,function(){


  //you can do something here
$("#yourimage").show();
      });
    },
    function(){
        $(".checkbutton", this).fadeOut(200,function(){
$("#yourimage").show();
});
 });

});
```

for more info refer to [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/)

Comment: Hi, the time span value doesn't help, yes, it appears faster, but after it is fully appear, then it will dissapear again.

Comment: ok i have edited my answer, if u want to do something after finishing of your animation you can do it by adding a function parameter to your fade in or fadeout function as i have do above

Comment: @Cong leong refer to JamCoope method which is best way to do this type of stuff , javascript is not more reliable than CSS, so u should give preference to CSS instead of using javascript

Answer (score 0):

You could just do this with CSS which is always better than doing this kind of thing with JavaScript.

```
.checkbutton {
    height: 40px;
    width: 209px;
    z-index: 2000;
    margin: 0 auto;

    /*
     * Note that I have added a transition and opacity
     */
    transition:200ms;
    opacity:0;
}

.imgforplaces_thumbnail1:hover .checkbutton{
    opacity:1;
}
```

Above we are using the CSS **:hover** pseudo-class on the .imgforplaces_thumbnail1 element and then we are effecting the .checkbutton's opacity when there is a hover over the parent element.

For more indepth look into the :hover pseudo-class read: [this blog post](http://www.codeitpretty.com/2013/06/how-to-use-css-hover-effects.html)

This will have the same desired effect because when you hover over the imageforplaces_thumbnail1 it will make the opacity go to 1 with a transition of 200 milliseconds

Here is a jsFiddle to show you how this works with just CSS and HTML: [click here](http://jsfiddle.net/uJ5wx/)